# Отобразить данные, полученные после регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Решил написать парсер на PHP.
При попытке отобразить данные, которые получены после регулярного выражения PHP выдаёт ошибку. Всё сохраняю в массив. При обращении к ячейке массива пишет, что элемента не существует.

Comment: Было бы здорово увидеть что на входе и что на выходе, а также сам код

Comment: <?php
    echo "What new?<br />";
    
    $result = [];
    $page = file_get_contents("http://**********.ru/*****");
    echo preg_match_all("/\<h2\>\<a href\=\".*\" title\=\".*\" class\=\".*\"\>.*\<\/a\>\<\/h2\>/i", $page, $result);
    echo $result[0];
?>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$html = '<h2><a href="http://localhost/1" title="1_title" class="1_class">1</a></h2><h2><a href="http://localhost/2" title="2_title" class="2_class">2</a></h2><h2><a href="http://localhost/3" title="3_title" class="3_class">3</a></h2>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$h2 = $doc->getElementsByTagName('h2');

foreach ($h2 as $value) {
    $a = $value->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0);
    echo $a->nodeValue.'<br>';
    echo $a->getAttribute('href').'<br>';
    echo $a->getAttribute('title').'<br>';
    echo $a->getAttribute('class').'<br>';
}
```

Не очень красиво (можно подправить согласно своей религии), но решает очень много проблем, с которыми вы встретитесь при использовании регулярных выражений для таких задач.

---

Что касается вашей регулярки:

```
preg_match_all('/<h2><a href="(.*?)" title="(.*?)" class="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/a><\/h2>/i', $page, $result);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Можно и так. Спасибо.